# WooCommerce: Get custom field from product variations and display it on the "additional information area"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to add a custom field to product variations, and display the custom field value on products in the "additional information area".

I'm working from ["WooCommerce: Add Custom Field to Each Product Variation"](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-custom-field-product-variation/).

The custom field is working fine, but I cannot seam to display the value on the product page.

This is what I have so far:

```php
// 1. Add custom field input @ Product Data > Variations > Single Variation
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'Add_custom_field_to_variations', 10, 3 );
function Add_custom_field_to_variations( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {  
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id' => 'custom_field[' . $loop . ']',
        'class' => 'short',
        'label' => __( 'Custom Field', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'custom_field', true ) 
    ));
}

// 2. Save custom field on product variation save
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'Save_custom_field_variations', 10, 2 );
function Save_custom_field_variations( $variation_id, $i ) {
    $custom_field = $_POST['custom_field'][$i];
    if ( isset( $custom_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'custom_field', esc_attr( $custom_field ) );
    }
}

// 3. Store custom field value into variation data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'Add_custom_field_variation_data' );
function Add_custom_field_variation_data( $variations ) {  
    $variations['custom_field'] = '<div class="woocommerce_custom_field">Custom Field: <span>' . get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], 'custom_field', true ) . '</span></div>';

    return $variations;
}

// 4. Display custom field on the additional information area
function Display_product_attributes2($product_attributes, $variations){
    $product_attributes['custom_field'] = [
        'label' => __('custom', 'text-domain'),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $variation_id, '_custom_field', true ),
    ];
    return $product_attributes;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'Display_product_attributes2', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `'value' => get_post_meta( $variation_id, '_custom_field', true )` you make use of the `$variation_id` while this is not defined.

So you can make use a foreach loop and `$variations->get_children();` instead to add a custom label & value in the "additional information area"

```php
// 4. Display custom field on the additional information area
function display_product_attributes( $product_attributes, $variations ) {
    // Get childIDs in an array
    $children_ids = $variations->get_children();

    foreach ( $children_ids as $child_id ) {
        $value = get_post_meta( $child_id, 'custom_field', true );

        // True
        if ( $value ) {
            // rows
            $product_attributes[ 'custom_field ' . $child_id ] = array(
                'label' => __('custom', 'woocommerce'),
                'value' => $value,
            );
        }
    }

    return $product_attributes;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'display_product_attributes', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Is it possible to only show the custom fields when a variation is selected? The above code show all custom fields all the time. thanks

Comment: @tiny yes, with jQuery. See how i applied this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62169489/11987538)