# Display SKU on the 'additional information area' for single and variable products

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to display the product's SKU inside the table row of single products Additional Information tab.

I tried using the `woocommerce_display_product_attributes` filter and have it displayed (sample of my code below) but it only works with *simple product*.

When using variable products with different SKU, the field are not updated when (dropdown select) variation is selected and only show blank. Is there a proper way to do this?

Here's my current code:

```php
// Displays SKU/Part# to Single product Additional information table rows
add_filter('woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'wc_display_sku_additional_info_table', 10, 2);
function wc_display_sku_additional_info_table( $product_attributes, $product ){
    // Get product SKU
    $get_sku = ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );

    $product_attributes[] = [
        'label' => __('SKU', 'woocommerce'),
        'value' => $get_sku,
    ];
    return $product_attributes;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should suffice, comment with explanation added to my code

- For both `single` and `variable` products, a SKU table row is added to the additional information tab.
- SKU table row is updated accordingly with the dropdown select menu for `variable` products

```php
function display_product_attributes( $product_attributes, $product ) {
    // Simple product
    if ( $product->is_type('simple' ) ) {
        // Get product SKU
        $get_sku = ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );

        // Add
        $product_attributes[ 'sku-field sku-field-single' ] = array(
            'label' => __('SKU', 'woocommerce'),
            'value' => $get_sku,
        );

    } 
    // Variable product
    elseif ( $product->is_type('variable' ) ) {
        // Get childIDs in an array
        $children_ids = $product->get_children();

        // Loop
        foreach ( $children_ids as $child_id ) {
            // Get product
            $product = wc_get_product( $child_id ); 

            // Get product SKU
            $get_sku = ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );

            // Add
            $product_attributes[ 'sku-field sku-field-variable sku-field-variable-' . $child_id ] = array(
                'label' => __('SKU', 'woocommerce'),
                'value' => $get_sku,
            );
        }
        ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // Hide all rows
            $( '.sku-field-variable' ).css( 'display', 'none' );

            // Change
            $( 'input.variation_id' ).change( function() {
                // Hide all rows
                $( '.sku-field-variable' ).css( 'display', 'none' );

                if( $( 'input.variation_id' ).val() != '' ) {
                    var var_id = $( 'input.variation_id' ).val();

                    // Display current
                    $( '.sku-field-variable-' + var_id ).css( 'display', 'table-row' );
                }
            });    
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }

    return $product_attributes;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'display_product_attributes', 10, 2);
```