# Display SKU on the 'additional information area' at the Beginning

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to display the SKU in the additional information in WooCommerce - not at the end of the table, but directly at the beginning.

I'm using [Display SKU on the 'additional information area' for single and variable products](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62169489/11987538) answer code.

I would like to solve it via `functions.php` and not change anything in the plugin code.

How do I have to adapt the code? Is it possible?

Comment: At the very top of the code (before 'simple product' comment), add the following `$new_row = array();` then rename `$product_attributes[` (2x in the code, where the comment tag 'add' is in front) to `$new_row[`  and change `return $product_attributes;` to `return $new_row + $product_attributes;`, 
that should suffice. Regards

Comment: Great. It works fine.
Many thanks for the help.