# update post meta for variable product when variation changes

Tags: php, woocommerce, product-variations

I've added a custom meta field for my variations. It’s a text input field. This works and it is present in db. I am trying to make this information behave as the weight parameter, that is updated in the additional info tab, when an other variation is selected:

```
//diameter
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variation_settings_fields', 10, 3 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );

function variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
// Text Field
echo '<p class="form-field dimensions_field">';
woocommerce_wp_text_input(
    array(
        'id'          => '_durchmesser[' . $variation->ID . ']',
        'label'       => __( 'Durchmesser', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => '',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Durchmesser einfügen.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_durchmesser', true )
    )
);
echo '</p>';
}

function save_variation_settings_fields( $post_id ) {
$text_field = $_POST['_durchmesser'][ $post_id ];
if ( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_durchmesser', esc_attr( $text_field ) );
}
}
```

Then i tried to bring this value into play for the additional information tab:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'display_diameter', 10, 2);

function display_diameter($product_attributes, $product){

//this gets all variation id’s
$test = $product->get_children();
//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($test);
//echo '</pre>';

//hardcoded since i do not know how to dynamically add the current variation id
$product_attributes['customfield'] = [
    'label' => __('Durchmesser'),
    'value' => get_post_meta( $test[2] , '_durchmesser', true ).' cm'
];

return $product_attributes;
```

}

The variation id is hard coded $test[2]. How can i bring the current variation id into play?
Is this done via ajax?

I made another test with the template variation.php and this works, but i don’t want to overburden the screen and rather display the specific info in the additional info tab.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'test_diameter' );
function test_diameter( $variations ) {
$variations['durchmesser'] = get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], '_durchmesser', true );
return $variations;
}
```

and in variation.php

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">
<div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">Durchmesser: {{{data.variation.durchmesser}}} cm</div>
</script>
```

thanks

Comment: See this [question + answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61853598/woocommerce-get-custom-field-from-product-variations-and-display-it-on-the-add/) & this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62169489/11987538). When you combine these 2 answers, you should arrive at a solution to your question. If you can't figure it out, just give me a call. Regards

Comment: thanks for the hint, i’ll try and eventually get back to you.

Comment: Ok, i tried, but it displays all fields for all variations in the add info tab. The foreach loop seems to grab them all. The variation specific info for all variations is shown.

Comment: That is indeed the case with the first link, however, the 2nd link contains a piece of jQuery. This allows you to show each row individually, 
depending on the choice when a variantion is selected.

Comment: This jQuery code returns «jQuery not defined». Is this due to loading jQuery library in the footer?

Comment: Your second suggestion works well, when loading jquery in the head. Now i have to find a solution for this snippet to work, when jquery is deferred. Thanks so far for your help.

Comment: I added the jquery snippet to my custom single-product.js then deferred jquery.min.js again and all works well. thanks again for your interest.